# NSViewController StoryBoard Opening Window Error

Tags: swift, nsbutton, nsviewcontroller

I'm working on a program with several view-controllers, all of which I open at various instances as sheets, by controlling dragging from a button on one viewcontroller to another viewcontroller, and by selecting "Sheet". This has always worked, until now when recently tried to add another viewcontroller and connect it similarly. When I click the button to open it though, it crashes and throws the error: (NSButton): missing setter or instance variable. When I use the new button to open an old viewcontroller, it works, but when I use an old button to open a new viewcontroller, it doesn't. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: I just figured out the problem so no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't specifying which viewController the data needed to be sent to so I made an if statement saying, "If this view controller, then" and "else" etc. which ended up working.